# A* algorithm to check if the graph k3 free

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory, a-star

I'm wondering if I can use A* algorithm to check if the graph is K3 free?? if yes how can I do that? How can I deal with f, g , and h functions.
if no what is the best algorithm to use except DFS and BFS.

Thanks

Comment: BFS. If there is K3 in graph, at least one edge will point to the vertice at the same level.

Answer (score 2):

A* is not an appropriate tool for this problem. Iterate through the edges in the graph and check whether their endpoints have a neighbor in common. user482594's BFS solution fails to detect K3s consisting of vertices at equal depth in the BFS tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So which algorithm you suggest to solve this problem?